# Is the following a valid MCMC sampler?

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo

I have a model with two variables $X_1$ and $X_2$.

In general, I would like to create a Gibbs sampler based on the conditionals $p(X_1 | X_2)$ and $p(X_2 | X_1)$.

However, computing either $p(X_2 | X_1)$ or $p(X_1 | X_2)$ is intractable. Though, they can be computed up to a normalization constant.

Fortunately, there is a function $f$ such that $p(X_2 | f(X_1))$ and $p(X_1| f(X_2))$ is tractable.

I wanted to know if the following is a valid sampler that has the guaranteed MCMC convergence.

1. randomly initialize $x_1$ and $x_2$
2. until convergence is reached, perform the following:

   2a. perform *one* Hastings step to get a new value for $x_1$ (i.e. one accept/reject step) for $p(X_1 | X_2)$ based on the proposal $p(X_1 | f(X_2))$.

   2b. perform *one* Hastings step analogously for $x_2$.

I am just not sure whether in order to get guaranteed convergence, 2a and 2b have to be run until convergence too (instead of taking one accept/reject step).

Comment: Do you really mean the proposal $p(X_{1}|f(X_{2}))$?
Can just perform Metropolis-Hastings step for each conditional in each Gibbs step.
1. Initialize $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$; 
2. a) propose X_{1,n+1}; calculate acceptance probability $\alpha$ for the conditional $p(X_{1,n+1}|X_{2,n})$. Accept it or reject; 
   b) do the same for conditional $p(X_{2}|X_{1})$;

Comment: 1) I'm not sure how it is possible that $p(X_2|X_1)$ is intractable but $p(X_2|f(X_1))$ is tractable.  2) Can you easily generate variates from $p(X_2|f(X_1))$ and $p(X_1|f(X_2))$?